# Node stream.Readable readable event fires twice

Tags: node.js, events, stream

## Is the behaviour describe in 3. below expected?

#### Why is a second `readable` event fired after `stream.read()` in the `readable` callback?

---

### stream.Readable emits `readable` twice

#### If I set a listener on `readable`, the `readable` event fires again after `stream.read()`

#### node version 5.12, windows 10

#### 1. If I read immediately after creating the stream, I get null

```
stream = fs.createReadStream(inFile);
result = stream.read();
```

[image]

#### 2. If I read after 200 msec, read succeeds and no further `readable` events are emitted

```
stream = fs.createReadStream(inFile);
function _main() {
    result = stream.read();
}
setTimeout(_main, delay);
```

[image: ![image](timeout.gif)]

#### 3. If I read in a call-back on the `readable` event, read succeeds but a second `readable` event is emitted

```
stream = fs.createReadStream(inFile);
stream.on('readable', () => {
    result = stream.read()
});
```

[image: ![image](onreabable.gif)]

---

#### [GIT Repo with complete working example](https://github.com/cool-Blue/node-file-streams)

Comment: I know this is old but were you able to figure out why?